# Como excluir todos arquivos JPG dentro de uma pasta usando PHP

Tags: php, delete

Tenho um script que importa fotos e cria miniaturas mini e medias dentro da pasta de cadastro e gostaria que depois que rodasse esse, ele apagasse as fotos originais.

A estrutura da pasta é assim:

```
pasta_fotos
--original1.jpg
--original2.jpg
--pasta_miniatura
----mini1.jpg
----mini2.jpg
--pasta_medio
----medio1.jpg
----medio2.jpg
```

O que preciso é que no fim do script ele apague as fotos originais, ou seja, todas que estão dentro do pasta_fotos, mas não excluir as outras fotos nem as outras pastas.

Excluir apenas:

```
--original1.jpg
--original2.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$files = glob('pasta_fotos/original*.jpg'); // obtém as imagens que começam com o nome "original"
foreach($files as $file){ // percorre os arquivos encontrados
  if(is_file($file))
    unlink($file); // remove o arquivo
}
```

Acredito que seja o suficiente. Se pretente fazer algo mais avançado da uma lida sobre as funções glob do PHP.

Comment: Obrigado, isso mesmo!

Comment: só alterei o original* para apenas *, cada arquivo tem um nome diferente